# One screen, three different operations

Tags: interface, fullscreen

I hope this question is allowed here but I am now stuck with a UI issue I have no idea how I'm going to handle intuitively.

The goal is to have a single screen which is displayed all day long on various computer stations dealing with storage. It is supposed to be operated by keyboard/mouse and a barcode scanner (the less keyboard/mouse the better). It's supposed to display four operations:

- Get an item from storage for section A
- Get an item from storage for section B
- Put an item back into storage (both from A or B, doesn't matter)
- Optional: Display where the item currently is (A, B, storage)

The "Get" operations both require that a textual entry is made and confirmed, the operation of putting back the item requires that a barcode is scanned and confirmed and the last operation requires that a barcode is entered either manually or by the barcode scanner. The coding itself is no issue but the question is: How should the UI be designed so it is immediately understandable to the user which operation he intends to perform. The user is little trained personnel mainly doing other things, each person uses this UI maybe 1-2 times / workday.

To be honest, my first approach was 4 columns with the storage on top and the shopfloor on the bottom but even I found this counterintuitive. Any ideas?

Comment: How many items are there? How do users first choose an item to get it out  of storage? Why do users scan when putting something back in to storage, but don't scan when taking it out of storage?

Comment: This question might get put on hold because the solution is very specific to your situation.

Comment: @SteveD: The system is basically based on an article number and batches whereas each article number contains n batches. If the user wants to get an item from storage, he/she will enter the article number (manually, it's not on the barcode). The barcode identifies a batch, so when the user puts the batch back into storage, the barcode will be scanned and the system knows about the correct article number by itself.

Comment: @SteveD; Yes, in fact I feared so :-) It is pretty specific, maybe one could write it as: How to present a number of 4 options to the user to make sure he/she selected the correct one even if the personnel is only little trained. Not really taking all the barcode/articlenumber stuff into account.

Comment: This UX:SO is not really for designing your solution for you (and this is why it might be put on hold), but given there doesn't seem to be many moving parts, this actually should be easy for you to solve. I am guessing one of the key parts is the field where the user enters the article code to trigger a search. The search result can now tell you where it is, as well as ask you want you want to do with it.

Comment: That's actually a pretty helpful input; why not go the other way round. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to this is the item number (irrespective of where it currently is)

- If you don't physically have the item, then it must be in storage, so
  you have to manually enter the item number to locate the
  item. The only actions are to send it to A or B.
- If you physically have the item, then it is not in storage, and the only
  actions are to put it back in storage using the barcode scanner.

Building a simple UI to support this should be very easy.

Comment: Thank you for the hint with seeing it "the other way round".